# Ребят срочно нужна помощь по верстке , браузер не адекватно видит код

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: Вот что видит браузер]

[image: вот что прописано в коде]

Есть меня в котором браузер не корректно выполняет код так же есть на сайте аналогичное меню которое работает вполне нормально, спрашивайте отвечу на все вопросы

Если голосуете против пожалуйста аргументируйте свое мнение

Comment: если Вы хотите получить ответ на свой вопрос, то оформите его соответственно, создайте минимальный, воспроизводимый пример: вставьте в вопрос *пример кода*(в форме редактирования вопроса Ctrl+K), добавьте разметку, css и опишите что работает не так как вы ожидаете, и кстати вставлять в вопрос пример кода **картинкой** не приветствуется

Comment: @IvanOrlov, пожалуйста, оформите правильно вопрос. Непосредственно сам исходный код(2-е изображение) приведите в виде текста, поскольку те кто разбирается в вопросе часто пытаются его воспроизвести и заставлять их перепечатывать текст, я считаю неверным. Первое же изображение я считаю критичным оставить, поскольку оно отображает реальную DOM-структуру. Также лучше убрать просьбы, побуждения и эмоции, чтобы в остатке осталась только информация представляющая важность для пользователей. И важно указать, что то что на изображении, отличается от приведенного кода, поскольку это не очевидно.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос должен содержать описание проблемы, код и желаемое поведение, а не `спрашивайте отвечу на все вопросы`

Comment: Подскажите как его закрыть

Comment: @IvanOrlov,  на SO закрывают вопросы, которые не соответствуют правилам ресурса. С Вашей стороны Вы можете привести его в надлежащий вид и тогда его не закроют. Вы можете его удалить если Вам это не нужно. Если же Вы оставите все как есть, то пользователи, у которых есть соответствующий рейтинг закроют его путём голосования, либо же его может закрыть модератор. На голосование вопрос попадает после того как у вопроса появляется три голоса "за закрытие"...т.е. три минуса, поэтому Ваш вопрос уже вынесен на голосование, более того с него уже оставили комментарии выше.

Comment: @IvanOrlov, Если Вы считаете что Ваш опыт может помочь другим пользователям, то его лучше привести в надлежащий вид.

Comment: @IvanOrlov, на вопрос уже ответили, и даже ответ принят, если его закрыть, могут быть негативные последствия. Могут заблокировать  автора вопроса, коим ты являешься, и в последствии не сможешь задавать вопросы, лучше всего его привести в надлежащий вид, и можно будет от минусов избавиться...  Если вопрос минусовали, то минус можно убрать, только после правки вопроса....

Comment: В тег А вложены другие теги А... Нельзя вкладывать ссылки в ссылки.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Браузер, видит Ваш код ровно в том виде, в котором Вы его написали и видит его адекватно.
Сейчас я постараюсь объяснить, что же все-таки случилось.

Для начала необходимо определиться с тем, что Вы видели, потому что, то что Вы показали на первом изображении **не является исходным кодом страницы**.
Для того чтобы увидеть исходный код страницы Вам необходимо:

1. Нажать на правую клавишу мыши
2. Выбрать пункт "просмотр кода страницы"

И итображаемый в данном случае код, будет соответствовать коду на втором изображении.
На первом же изображении Вами показана **реальная DOM-структура документа** - реальное дерево элементов с которым работает браузер, которое он пытается построить на основе Вашего исходного кода.

В соответствии с этим Ваш вопрос сводится к следующему:
*Почему реальная DOM-структура страницы отличается от исходного кода?*

Ответ прост:
**Реальная DOM-структура не может соответствовать исходному коду, потому что исходный код содержит ошибки.**(в рамках формата HTML4.1 - см. UPD1)

Браузер как приложение не имеет возможности переносить ошибки из исходного кода в реальную DOM-структуру, посколько тогда его элементы бы вели себя непредсказуемым образом и могли бы приводить к аварийному завершению работы приложения.
В качестве основы браузер принимает стандарты W3C и чем больше Ваш код будет им соответствовать, тем больше реальная DOM-структура будет соответствовать Вашему коду.

Ошибки браузер выявляет еще на стадии синтаксического анализа исходного кода.
После чего, на стадии построения дерева браузер пытается разрешить ошибки.

**В чем была Ваша ошибка?**
В соответствии с правилами вложения тега `<a>`

> Любая ссылка является встроенным элементом, поэтому для нее действуют те же правила, что и для встроенных элементов. 
>   А именно, нельзя размещать внутри тега `<a>` блочные элементы...

Поэтому браузер увидев `<div>`ы внутри тега `<a>`, просто вытащил их наружу.

---

**UPD1**

Написанное Выше описывает поведение в конкретно взятом случае и как верно заметил пользователь @Air, в "новом" стандарте HTML5 уже другие правила, поэтому
следует чуть подробнее разобрать данный случай и уточнить стандарты.

Для начала:

> **Версия стандарта HTML5 допускает вложение блочных элементов, если те в свою очередь не предполагают интерактивного поведения.**

Отсюда возникает вопрос:
*Каким образом браузер определяет с каким именно стандартом сравнивать Ваш документ и как он определяет версию документа?*

Для этого необходимо познакомиться с понятием DOCTYPE:

> **Что такое DOCTYPE?**
>
> DOCTYPE-объявление располагается в самом начале кода HTML-документа и необходимо для переключения браузера в режим соответствия стандартам. Только в этом режиме можно рассчитывать на единообразное отображение HTML-страницы в разных браузерах. (Браузер — это программа для просмотра сайтов.)
>
> Без DOCTYPE (либо при неправильном DOCTYPE) браузеры отображают страницу в режиме совместимости со старыми браузерами — вплоть до имитации их ошибок (багов). Кроме того, современные возможности (например, поддержка CSS-свойства padding для элемента IMG) доступны только в режиме соответствия стандартам. Следует всегда снабжать HTML-документы DOCTYPE-объявлением.

Соответственно, если Вы осознанно хотите переключиться в режим соответствия HTML5, Вам **обязательно** необходимо указать в начале документа DOCTYPE.

Для HTML5 он будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Для других версий стандарта DOCTYPE можно посмотреть перейдя на следующую страницу:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: Дай пример, как меню работает и как должно работать?

Comment: Михаил, информация устаревшая.... В тег `a`, даже очень можно уже вставлять блочные элементы....

Comment: @Air, спасибо за замечание. Я поправлю ответ

Comment: @IvanOrlov, я допустил неточность в ответе и в ближайшее время её исправлю. Пока что напишу здесь что информация описанная выше актуальна для версии стандарта HTML4.1. Версия HTML5 допускает вложение блочных элементов, если те в свою очередь не предполагают интерактивного поведения. Но для того чтобы браузер понимал, что этот документ соответствует HTML5, это необходимо указать в исходном коде, для этого необходимо указать в самом начале документа `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Comment: ответ обновлён.

Comment: там ссылка в ссылке. А не див в ссылке. Его и HTML5 не проглотит

Comment: Не знаю почему мой  комментарий удалили, напишу еще раз. Данный ответ абсолютно неправильный. Проблема в том что в ссылку, вложены другие ссылки, чего делать нельзя и блоки  с доктайпом тут не при чем. Более того в тег А можно и нужно вкладывать блочные элементы

Comment: @l2banners, я видел Ваш комментарий, который был под вопросом..не под моим ответом (возможно вы его имели в виду?). В остальном я уже видел замечания по поводу ссылок  и когда я сам скомпаную всю информацию в  доступном виде - я обязательно внесу данную правку в ответ и если Вы действительно хотите помочь, то лучше всего привести в комментарии референс, на который я мог бы перейти, ознакомится, после чего детально все разъяснить в ответе. С наскоку за 5 минут у меня такой референс найти не получилось. Если поможете - то буду благодарен.

Comment: @МихаилРебров https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

Comment: @МихаилРебров 12.2.2 Nested links are illegal
Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements.

Comment: @l2banners, спасибо за помощь. Я подготовлю ответ, который будет максимально соответствовать действительности.